# Real time update cart based on the number of uploaded images

Tags: cart

Good morning,

I need a system to uploads multiple images in front end, but I would like based on the number of images uploaded, it can be updated in real time the cart with the right amount.

That is, if the customer charge 1 photos the price will be $ 10.00
but I would like that if the customer charge 3 photos the price is updated to $ 30.00

Is possible to do this? There is already an extension?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think you can achieve this with custom options (custom options tab on product edit page). Add N custom options with type file, each one with the price of 10$ and don't make them mandatory (or maybe just make the first one mandatory).
The only limitation of this approach is that the customer will be limited to max N images uploaded.